# Stretch div to one side of the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">content</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="map">map goes here</div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

.container is centered an not fullwidth.
I need the .map div to stretch till the right border of the browser window.
How is it possible?

Comment: You forgot a quotation mark after `class="container`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is on the [main page bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire
>   width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you need is specific style on .container to override default bootstrap .container:

```
body .container {
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not what I need. I need the container to stay for example 1170px wide on md screens but .map should overlap the container and stretch to the right browser side.

Not sure it's possible with css only. maybe js can help?

Comment: Don't add an answer to your own question unless it's actually an answer. Instead update and improve the question.